# Can you use a commercial code signing certificate on multiple programs and installers?

Tags: certificate, code-signing

Is it possible to use a commercial code signing certificate on multiple programs and installers?

I would like to purchase a Comodo certificate but due to the cost I need to use it to sign multiple programs and installers.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have 10 apps, each has an installer! It's a hobby so I don't to be spending 1000's on certificates but I'm being asked why my apps aren't signed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never purchased a cert from Comodo, but there are generally no limits on the numbers of items you're allowed to sign, only a limit on the amount of time (1 or more years, typically) for which the cert is valid.

Update: From the [Comodo Code-Signing FAQ](http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/code-signing-faq.html):

> **Is there a limit to the amount of
> applications allowed to be signed with
> a Code Signing Certificate?**
>
> Comodo
> does not limit you to any specific
> number. You can sign as many
> applications with a Code Signing
> Certificate as you wish, provided that
> the applications are going to be used
> for and distributed by the
> Organization that owns the
> certificate.

Comment: That sounds promising I just want to verify that is the case. Thanks

Comment: @StevenL As my update confirms, it is indeed. Answers to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155241/cheapest-java-code-signing-certificate-not-self-signed) cover options for signing Java apps, but I believe the same certs should work for other code as well.

Answer (score 5):

We use a Comodo certificate at work, there is no limit on the amount of code that you can sign.  You buy the certificate for a year, 2 years etc and can sign as much as you want during that time span.  Also, if you timestamp everything correctly, the signed code does not expire when the certificate expires, so once you sign it (with a valid timestamp), it is signed until you have to recompile.